# Java replaceAll do not replace string

Tags: java, regex

I am parsing through some XML and sanitizing some fields.

I'm trying to do the following in Java:

```
nameField = nameField.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z\\d\\s\\.,'&amp;]", "");
```

I do **not** want to replace any letters of the alphabet, any number, any whitespace, any period, any comma, any single quote or (this is where my issue is) the *literal string* `&amp;`.

But I do want to replace occurrences of a single `&` or a single `;`

But obviously my Regex as it sits won't work. It'll leave in all `&` and all `;`.

For example, say the string of `K&W@#9$9(AR;.0 O&amp;` is found, my expected result would be: `KW99AR.0 O&amp;`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `&amp;` inside character class will match `&`, `a`, `m`, `p` or `;`.

Comment: Correct, which is what I'm *not* looking to do.  I attempted to note that the Regex won't work as it sits for that reason, that I want to match a string and not all the individual parts of the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you simplify your regular expression and just go with a lookahead/lookbehind:

```
//                  |"&" not followed by "amp;"
//                  |          | or
//                  |          | ";" not preceded by "&amp"
nameField.replaceAll("&(?!amp;)|(?<!&amp);", "");
```

The output for `"K&W@#9$9(AR;.0 O&amp;"` would be:

```
KW@#9$9(AR.0 O&amp;
```

**Edit**

Then, you can chain this with a cleanup, leaving your desired characters only. Here, I added the `;` and `&` to the exclude list, since they're already cleaned up when "standalone" by the previous operation.

Also, you don't need to escape the dot in a custom character class.

```
.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z\\d\\s.,;&]", "");
```

The two chained invocations will return:

```
KW99AR.0 O&amp;
```

**Notes**

- As mentioned by [Tushar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2025923/tushar), sequences of characters in a custom character class are not considered as sequences but alternate individual characters.
- General rule of thumb: careful about using regex to parse markup. You may very well end up with a bigger mess. Regular expressions are not made to parse markup or languages with a grammar.
- Your specific case is safe enough, but remember there are other XML entities such as `&gt;`, `&lt;` etc.

Comment: I'm assuming you're suggesting that I use your solution to replace all occurrences of `&` and `;` that are not part of the `&amp;` string. And then to do another regex such as `[^a-zA-Z\d\s\.,'&;]` that will replace all of the remaining characters I don't want (such as `@` and `#`) to result in the desired string of `KW99AR.0 O&amp;`?

Comment: @Jsmith yes I haven't read your question well enough. There's likely a way to inline all this in one regex. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: @Jsmith actually, which *are* the characters you want replaced, aside from single `&` and `;`? You still have a dot in your expected output, for instance.

Comment: anything that isn't part of `a-zA-Z\d\s\.,'` or the string of `&amp;` .  Meaning I want to keep those and I'm not sure what other junk characters may be passing through. I've had junk such as `�` (not sure how the browser will interpret that character) show up.

Comment: The "junk" characters likely denote some encoding issue. I'd go with a chained invocation so you first remove the ones that need context, then clean up with the rest. Let me update the answer...

Comment: @Jsmith done. For the "dirty" (wrong encoding) characters, you may want to insert another operation, or find a clever unicode range / class, etc. although you probably want this fixed at the source, rather than with regex.

Comment: oh I'd love to have to not deal with it.  But alas, I have no control over the source, I'm just a lowly peon dealing with what was given to me :( Your solution should work perfectly now, thanks for the assistance!

Comment: @Jsmith you're welcome. And if it's any consolation, I feel ya, been there too!

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it:

```
nameField = nameField.replaceAll("[^\\w&\\.\\s';,]","")
           .replaceAll("&amp;","%")
           .replaceAll("[&;]","")
           .replaceAll("%","&amp;");
```

Comment: this only works if you're guaranteed never to have a `%` in the source.  (And your `replaceAll("&;","")` is wrong anyway, and should be `replaceAll("[&;]","")`)

Comment: Thanks, corrected [&;]. Any % are already removed by the first replaceAll, so yes, I can guarantee there is no % after that .